# TypeError: Cannot read property 'ensure' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Hey guys I'm having a problem. I'm trying to make a points bot. Using the `give` command will achieve this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'ensure' of undefined`

Code having the error:

```
client.points.ensure(`${message.guild.id}-${user.id}`, {
user: message.author.id,
guild: message.guild.id,
points: 0,
level: 1
```

Comment: `client.points` is undefined, do this `if (client && client.points) { client.points.ensure (..... }`

Comment: Sorta fixed? I don't recieve errors but it won't even change the value. But that's a question for another day, thanks!